# binary operator expected in win-bash

Tags: windows, macos, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that will run on both Mac and Windows by using [win-bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) for the windows side, since it doesn't have to be installed.
However, Mac and Windows seem to have different opinions of syntax.

For example, I have the following script thus far:

```
echo "Setup..."
shopt -s expand_aliases #make sure aliases work
if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]; then
    alias p4cli=./bin/p4
else
    alias p4cli=p4  
fi

echo "Checking login status..."
p4cli groups > .trash
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    p4cli login
fi
echo "Done!"
```

This fails with:

```
[: ==: binary operator expected
```

On windows (win-bash) but works just fine on Mac (which I'm going to assume is the more correct one... since it's actually Unix).

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I bet you don't have a `uname` cmd in your windows environment. Best to turn on shell debugging/trace feature with `set -vx`  and `set +vx` to turn off. Then you can see each cmd as executed with variable substitions in place. Good luck.

Comment: actually, win-bash includes uname

Comment: `cmd; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then ...` is more idiomatically written `if cmd; then ...` or simply `cmd || ...` if the fallback is a simple single action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try single `=` instead of double `==`:

```
if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ]; then
```

They both mean string equality check inside a test, but the single equal sign for comparison is POSIX-compliant, whereas the double equal sign isn't - it just works for the current bash / ksh as a syntactic sugar for readability (will fail for older shells as well).

Comment: bingo :) That was it. Thanks!